# Write a new file in selected directory with OpenDocumentTree: transform Uri in path

Tags: java, android, writefile, action-open-document-tree

My app has to save a new excel file in a user-selected directory.

The user select the directory with OpenDocumentTree picker directory picker. This intent returns an Uri.

I'm not able to transform Uri in path for the write function. How can I do? Thanks a lot.

```
final ActivityResultLauncher<Uri> mDirRequest = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(Uri result) {

                path = somethingIdontknow;

                try {
                    File file = new File(path, "goofy.xlsx");
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    workbook.write(out);
                    out.close();

                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
```

......

```
mDirRequest.launch(Uri.parse(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI));
```

I tried to implement a lot of suggestions from stackoverflow, but I've not resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You will not transform an uri in a path to begin with.

You can create a DocumentFile instance for the obtained uri.

After that use DocumentFile:createFile() to get an uri for the created file for which you open an InputStream and write to it.

Comment: Thank you. Can you give me some example code of your technique?

Comment: Lesson one of Storage Access Framework: How to create a file in a directory choosen by ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the ContentResolver and the openFileDescriptor method to get a ParcelFileDescriptor object.

Here is an example how it can looks like:

```
final ActivityResultLauncher<Uri> mDirRequest = registerForActivityResult(
    new ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree(),
    new ActivityResultCallback<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(Uri result) {

            Uri fileUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(result, "pippo.xlsx");

            ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
            try {
                OutputStream outputStream = resolver.openOutputStream(fileUri);
                workbook.write(outputStream);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Sorry. You select a directory and try to write to it. That will not go as you cannot open an outputstream for a directory.

Comment: yes you are right i didnt tested the code. i edited the code now and chenge it

Comment: Thank you for your suggest, but I got:  E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: it.linuxp.psswordlist, PID: 16956
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URI: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ATryagain/goofy.xlsx
Where is the error?

Comment: are you sure that you have the permission to read the file. and the file does exists?
if yes then you should be sure to use the getContentResolver method of your Activity or Fragment

Comment: The file doesn't exist. It's a new file. I'm using OpenDocumentTree to select the directory where I'm going to save a new file. Sorry, maybe my first question is ambigouos...

Comment: `. i edited the code now and chenge it` It is still nonsense, impossible not working code.

Comment: Sorry, I also tried manually creating the file (in /Downolad/Puppi/goofy.xlsx) before the launch of my app. I set those permissions:             Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.        The result is still: ava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URI: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ADownload%2FPuppi/goofy.xlsx